# Enabling a block to inherit the settings of a sub theme

Tags: blocks

Being relatively new to Drupal, I apologize in advance if what I'm saying is unclear, but I'd imagine that a fix should be simple enough:

Basically, I'd like to add a header block that functions identically to the other block regions on my Drupal site. At the moment, the text of that header is not responsive to window size, unlike the rest of the site. How can I inherit the default settings of my theme when creating a new block?

Thanks in advance, a solution to this would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You can style a block however you like - since it is going in the header, it sounds like a css issue for the header region. I would start by comparing the css for the content and/or footer regions with that of the header.  If all else fails, you can theme individual blocks - [here](https://drupal.org/node/104319) is some info.